# Inserting rows in MySQL table from existing rows(same table) based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, sql-insert

Hello everyone,

I have following table in MySQL database.

```
   id   report_date value    event_id   event_start_date    event_end_date
    1   5/31/1978   10          
    1   6/30/1978   20          
    1   7/31/1978   30          
    1   8/31/1978   40          
    1   9/30/1978   70          
    1   10/31/1978  90          
    1   11/30/1978  10         a           11/25/1978              11/29/1978
    1   12/31/1978  30          
    1   1/31/1979   50          
    2   7/31/2012   28          
    2   8/31/2012   40          
    2   9/30/2012   60          
    2   10/31/2012  100        b            10/2/2012              10/4/2012
    2   11/30/2012  120         
    2   12/31/2012  130         
    2   1/31/2013   140
```

I want to add rows between event start date and event end date for that id with value as zero and these dates will be placed as report date. So the resulting table should be like this:

```
id  report_date value   event_id    event_start_date    event_end_date
1   5/31/1978   10          
1   6/30/1978   20          
1   7/31/1978   30          
1   8/31/1978   40          
1   9/30/1978   70          
1   10/31/1978  90          
1   11/30/1978  10          a        11/25/1978           11/29/1978
1   11/25/1978  0           a        11/25/1978           11/29/1978
1   11/26/1978  0           a        11/25/1978           11/29/1978
1   11/27/1978  0           a        11/25/1978           11/29/1978
1   11/28/1978  0           a        11/25/1978           11/29/1978
1   11/29/1978  0           a        11/25/1978           11/29/1978
1   12/31/1978  30          
1   1/31/1979   50          
2   7/31/2012   28          
2   8/31/2012   40          
2   9/30/2012   60          
2   10/31/2012  100          b        10/2/2012           10/4/2012
2   10/2/2012   0            b        10/2/2012           10/4/2012
2   10/3/2012   0            b        10/2/2012           10/4/2012
2   10/4/2012   0            b        10/2/2012           10/4/2012
2   11/30/2012  120         
2   12/31/2012  130         
2   1/31/2013   140
```

I am not able to find a way to do it. someone please help me out on this.
Thanks

Comment: Please include the code you tried

Comment: yes, I want to add rows for any records falling between a particular start and end date.

Comment: Whatever you are encoding into this table, ie whatever its rows mean, it is probably much simpler to record in & process from separate tables.